# how can i make in kubernetes post every 1 minute to my "www.exampleapi/api/main" endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, cron

I need assistance with configuring my Kubernetes cluster to send a POST request to the "www.exampleapi/api/main" endpoint every minute. My API is developed using .NET Core, and I'm looking for guidance on implementing this recurring task within my Kubernetes environment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the purpose of this, but if you need to call this endpoint on each pod to determine if the pod can take request then you can use readiness and liveness probe.

If you need to determine at least one pod is ready to take input then assuming you are using ingress then you can do similar with ingress depending on the ingress you are suing.

If it's not to keep alive but for another purpose then you can use a cron job which is a pod that can run on regular intervals defined by you. This pod can be based on curl images so you can ping this url with just a simple shell script.